# How to serve a file for download from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, csv

So this is probably a simple question, but I've never done it before.

I have a Rails action that queries a database and creates a csv string from the query result.

I'd like to take the query string, put it into a .csv file, and when the user makes the http request associated with this method, the .csv file will download onto the user's machine.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

The file is sending from rails, but my angular app on the front end (that requested the csv) is not downloading it.

Here is the angular code I'm using to request the file from the rails app

```
$scope.csvSubmit = function() {
  var csv = $.post('http://ip_addr:3000/api/csv', { 'input': $scope.query_box });
  csv.done(function(result){
     //empty - after the request is sent I want the csv file to download
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `send_file` method, passing the path to the file as the first argument, as see in [Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file).

**UPDATE**

You can use a temporary file to save the CSV, like this:

```
require 'tempfile'

# automatically creates a file in /tmp
file = Tempfile.new('data.csv', 'w')
file.write('my csv')
file.close

send_file(file.path)

# remove the file from /tmp
file.unlink
```

**UPDATE 2: AngularJS download**

There are two ways to accomplish this: you can add a hidden href to download the file in the page and click it, or redirect the user to the Rails URL that sends the file when he clicks in the button. Note that the redirect will use parameters in the url, so it won't work well depending on the structure of `query_box`.

To add a hidden href to the page with the CSV:

```
$scope.csvSubmit = function() {
  var csv = $.post('http://ip_addr:3000/api/csv', { 'input': $scope.query_box });
  csv.done(function(result){
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(result);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'filename.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
  })
}
```

To use the redirect:

```
$scope.csvSubmit = function() {
  var url = 'http://ip_addr:3000/api/csv/?' + 'input=' + encodeURI($scope.query_box);
  window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: I see. But first I have to create a csv, and if I do that I'm not sure where it appears within the rails file structure.

Comment: Thanks! The file is definitely sending now, but my angular app on the front end is not downloading it. Rails console shows "Sent file results.csv (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 897ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)" But a download never occurred.

Comment: Try to change the send_file call to something like this: `send_file(file.path, type: 'application/octet-stream')`. If it still doesn't work, try changing the type to `text/csv`. You can try adding `dispoition: :inline` too.

Comment: neither of those force the download

Comment: As you're using AngularJS as frontend, can you update the question with the javascript snippet used to access the file and forward it to the user? that would be much better

Comment: I added the angular code I use to request the file. Thanks for all your guidance

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this plenty of times before. You need to set the response headers to get the browser to force the download.

I like to use the [comma gem](https://github.com/comma-csv/comma) for rendering csv. Using the gem all you need to do is add the following lines to your controller action.

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.csv do 
     response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
     response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=books.csv'
     render :csv => Book.limited(50)  
   end
 end
```

Then you just use the csv format and it works.

If you don't want to use comma. Just change the render line to render your csv string:

```
render :plain => csv_string_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`send_data`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) to generate a downloadable file from a string in just one line:

```
    send_data @your_data, type: 'text/csv', disposition: 'attachment', filename: 'books.csv'
```